# Retrieve checkbox data in mysql with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

How can I retrieve previous saved data in mysql with checkbox to show what is saved? here is my form:

```
<?php
    try {
        $query = "select * from CONSULTA where user_id = '$user_id'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                $sick = $row['sick'];
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
?>

<form name="histo" id="histo" method="post">
    <div class="row-fluid grid">
        <label class="control-label"><b><?php echo $translate->__('Do you have any of the following symptoms'); ?>? :</b></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox1" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="1" name="sick[]" type="checkbox"<?php if ($sick == '1') {echo ' checked="checked"';} ?>></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Arrhythmias'); ?>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox2" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="2" name="sick[]" type="checkbox"<?php if ($sick == '2') {echo ' checked="checked"';} ?>></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Heart murmur'); ?>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox3" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="3" name="sick[]" type="checkbox"<?php if ($sick == '3') {echo ' checked="checked"';} ?>></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Stroke'); ?>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox3" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="4" name="sick[]" type="checkbox"<?php if ($sick == '4') {echo ' checked="checked"';} ?>></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Angina'); ?>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox3" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="5" name="sick[]" type="checkbox"<?php if ($sick == '5') {echo ' checked="checked"';} ?>></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Other'); ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_GET[user_id]; ?>" />
    <?php if (!empty($visit)) { echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />'; } else { echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="crear" />';} ?>

    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='<?php $translate->__('Save History'); ?>' />
</form>
<div id="loading4" style="display:none;"><img src="img/ajax-loaders/loading4.gif" /></div>
<div id="oh"></div>
```

Here is the data saved into DB:

```
sick  1, 3, 5
```

But is not show the checked in the checkbox...where is the error?

Comment: What is the value of `$sick`?

Comment: You should be preparing statements with [named parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of just stuffing in arbitrary user data. Things like `$user_id` should not be directly in your query.

Comment: @u_mulder the values in DB are these=  1, 3, 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are constructing a prepared statement and passing in (directly) a variable. That is not correct. In PDO you are either using `?` or `:user_id`, for instance, then we must bind the param after preparing the statement, please observe:

```
$query = "select * from CONSULTA where user_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bindParam(1, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

This will make it so your query is proper. However, I don't see how your data is stored, while you've shown `1,3,5`. If that's the case, then that is a CSV string that you need to explode and then compare against.

```
$sick = explode(',', $row['sick']);
```

Then you need to change your conditional statement. For this example, I'll use a ternary operator.

```
<?php echo in_array(1, $sick)? 'checked="checked"': ''; ?>
```

Replace `1` in the above line with `2,3,4,5` depending on your line of code.

This should resolve it.

Comment: I have an error here `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''; ?>></span></div> <?php echo' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` and I change this part `$sick = explode(',', $sick);` to this one = `$sick = explode(',', $row['sick']);`

Comment: @joaquin Try again with the code I have, please, I omitted an `'`

Comment: Hi again, not show me the check in the selected checkbox...I put this `<?php echo $sick; ?>` and show me Array...can you help me

Comment: @joaquin You need the ternary operator, `<?php echo in_array(1, $sick)? 'checked="checked"': ''; ?>`, not `<?php echo $sick; ?>`

Comment: yes I know, I insereted like you put it but not show me the check in the 1, 3, 5 box of checkbox...

Comment: I insert the data with this form `$sick = is_array($_POST['sick'])? implode(', ', $_POST['sick']): $_POST['sick'];` `INSERT INTO CONSULTA (sick,user_id) VALUES (:sick, :user_id); $stmt->bindParam(':sick', $sick);  $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id']);  $stmt->execute();`

Comment: I don't know why before don't works...but I tried and tried and now I just copy and paste and works!! thank you for your support! best regards!